# ASP.Net Web Forms Application Pool settings

Tags: webforms, application-pool

We have an application pool and an old asp.net 2.0 webforms application using a proprietary library to connect to the database.

We face OutOfMemoryExceptions and as the library is a black box that we cannot change. I am trying to ensure that Application Pool settings are correctly set.

The webserver has 8 GB of Memory installed and the settings of the application pool are:

**Recycling**

Private Memory Limit (KB): 0
Regular Time Interval (minutes): 0
Request.Limit: 0
Virtual Memory Limit(KB): 3145728

Do you believe that it is correct?

Exception message:

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
ContentType: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.set_SqlGuid(SqlGuid value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlValueInternal(SqlBuffer value, Byte tdsType, Int32 typeId, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at Adam.Core.DataMapper.PagingDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at Adam.Core.DataMapper.Fields.GuidTableField.AssignReader(IDataReader reader, Int32 columnIndex)
   at Adam.Core.DataMapper.ItemBase.AssignReader(IDataReader reader, SqlMappings mappings)
   at Adam.Core.DataMapper.ExtendedItemBase.AssignReader(IDataReader reader, SqlMappings mappings)
   at Adam.Core.Records.RecordCollection.Load(SearchExpression expression, String sortOrder, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 recordsPerPage, Boolean& isLastPage, Int32 maxRecords, RecordLoadOptions options)
   at Adam.Core.Records.RecordCollection.Load(SearchExpression expression, String sortOrder, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 recordsPerPage, Boolean& isLastPage, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Adam.Core.DataMapper.ExtendedItemBaseCollection.Load(SearchExpression expression, String sortOrder)
   at AssetFilePage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\App\WEBAPP.WebSite\file.aspx.cs:line 27
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using the settings below as a starting point:

Private Memory Limit (KB): 1048576

Regular Time Interval (minutes): 1440

Request.Limit: 10000

Virtual Memory Limit(KB): 1048576

Setting the Private and Virtual memory limits to 1Gb, having a regular recycle (24hr) and some kind of request limit (0 is unlimited). It would be a case of monitoring your app and fine tune the below til you get the sweet spot.

See here for more info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc745955.aspx